# Programación de juegos 2D de bajo nivel (C++/lua...), Que escoger?

Tags: c++, lua, motor-de-juego, 2d

Escribo este post con la intención de averiguar que lenguaje//librerias me recomiendan para la creación de juegos 2D de bajo nivel.

No quiero usar engines, quiero añadir conocimientos de programación, y con engines no se aprende demasiado la metodología.

Que tipo de juegos trato de hacer? Juegos en 2D, estilo arcade/game boy/game boy advance. El objetivo es ir haciendo juegos simples hasta llegar a la meta final, que sería un juego de pokemon de GBA el cual incluye base de datos, animaciones, sprites, tiles, múltiples interfaces gráficas (combates, menú...), inteligencia artificial rudimentaria (sacar al pokemon idóneo a luchar, ataques eficaces...) y como extra, exportación a Android (no es un requisito fundamental). Lo usaría como proyecto final de carrera.

Tecnologías que me planteo usar según el objetivo y sus características: (lo expondré a pros y contras)

C++: con librerías como SDL y Allegro.

Pros: - Total control absoluto del juego. - Conocimientos muy útiles para mi carrera profesional. - Exportación a Android posible.

Contras: - Poca información en general y menos en español. - Requiere de muchos conocimientos de los que aún creo que no dispongo.

Lua: con el framework love2d.

Pros: - Tan ligero como C++, y menos complejidad. - Mucha información 
(en inglés) y un foro bastante activo y grande. - Demostrada la posible creación de juegos GB y GBA con juegos como mari0 (Super Mario Portal)

Contras: - No se tiene un control tan absoluto como con C++ al usar un framework mucho mas elavorado, cosa que no me hace demasiada gracia. - Difícil exportación a Android

Para mí están empatados viéndolo de este modo, necesito a ese experto que me añada un pro o contra más a una de las dos tecnologías para acabar de convencerme, basándose en el objetivo a programar y sus características.

Un saludo!!

Comment: Yo te recomiendo C++ y hacerte un proxy empezando por SDL.
Mirate esta web: http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/index.php

Comment: @Valentino ¡bienvenido! Es una muy linda pregunta... Y al mismo tiempo es una lástima que busque respuestas basadas en opiniones (y un tanto amplias), que probablemente terminen cerrando tu pregunta... Estaba pensando cómo ayudarte a orientarla hacia lo que se busca en SOes, pero es tanto que no sé por dónde empezar, salvo referirte a [help/dont-ask] y esperar que se te ocurra cómo orientarla

Comment: Más que nada apuntas a aprender los conceptos de desarrollo de vídeo juegos y a cómo hacerlos desde 0. Eso me parece muy bueno, así luego podrás utilizar herramientas que faciliten la implementación, comprendiendo cómo funciona es más valioso,  estás usando una estrategia bottom up. Te recomiendo este tutorial [Handmade hero](https://handmadehero.org/) (en inglés, lastimosamente). Es una serie que sigue en desarrollo.

Comment: Gracias a todos por las respuestas, seguiré el handmade hero, a ver que me aporta, un saludo a todos! Intentaré reeditar la pregunta para que sea más objetiva. Creo que lo haré al estilo pros y contras, y que un experto lo valore para que se decante por cual es la mejor, desde la objetividad. Un saludo a todos y gracias por la cálida bienvenida, me encanta esta página :)

Answer (score -2):

Querer hacer un juego como el snake o peor aún, el pokemon, en C++ o LUA sin utilizar un motor tiene tan poco sentido como querer programarlo en binario. Incluso en las consolas hoy en día se usa motores. Es ponerte palos en las ruedas tu mismo.

Pero puedes usar un motor. Lo puedes hacer en C++. Y lo puedes hacer sin renunciar a programar en bajo nivel.
Con **[UNREAL ENGINE 4](https://www.unrealengine.com/)**. Por ejemplo tienes un [tutorial para 2D](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/2D_Game_making_-_video_series), en inglés.

Que tiene la importante ventaja de que está el código disponible. Y puedes aprender mucho más leyendo y modificando el código de profesionales de primer nivel de la industria. Programar no es solo escribir código. Programar es trabajar en equipo, ser capaz de entender lo que escriben otros y modificarlo para introducir nuevas funcionalidades, mejoras, optimizaciones, etc sin romper lo que ya hay.

Como inconveniente la documentación de UE4 no es tan buena como en otros motores. Y convertir un juego de PC a Android puede costar casi lo mismo que hacerlo nuevo.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Estoy de acuerdo con Arnau, e incidiendo en ello, debo decir que lo que yo quiero hacer es dar órdenes al hardware, no al software, y sí, quiero crear un juego. Por ejemplo, no quiero ponerle mp3 a un juego, como por ejemplo en CoronaSDK, o que me bloquee según ciertos formatos, lo que quiero es crear una serie de funciones que a partir del protocolo MIDI me cree una canción. La cuestión es programarlo. Podrás decir que me complico, si, pero no puedes negar que aprenderé de ello. Solo quiero que alguien experimentado me aconseje que tecnología de las expuestas debo  usar.

Comment: @ArnauCastellví es un hecho objetivo que un "no programador" NO puede scriptear; pues todo script es un programa. Y desde luego es falso que "programar en Java es scriptear". ¿Acaso afirmas que Eclipse, Minecraft o Netbeans son scripts? Valentio: ¿Quieres una función del tipo `play("cancion.mid",instrumento)` o quieres implementar tu la lectura del fichero mid y el envío de órdenes a la tarjeta de sonido?

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44868/discussion-on-answer-by-jose-antonio-dura-olmos-programacion-de-juegos-2d-de-baj).

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Lo que quiero exactamente es programar esa función play() no que me venga hecha ya. Quiero ver el trasfondo de los juegos, su base mas primitiva, quiero poder saborear mínimamente el trabajo que tuvieron que hacer en 1995 para crear pokemon rojo y azul y meter el juego entero en un cartucho de 1 MB.

Comment: @Valentio hay cosas que no puedes hacer a menos que implementes tu propio hardware, como es el caso de "programar esa función `play()`". Eso significa que tendrías que implementar el software para interactuar con ese hardware (donde estaría tu función `play()`) y luego el software de tu vídeo juego. Básicamente, lo que estás preguntando es "¿cómo crear mi propio nintendo?", pero eso es demasiado amplio para este sitio.

Comment: @Valentio en realidad sobre esas cosas hay más detalles que datan de años atrás a los 90, como puedes ver en [este vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tfh0ytz8S0k) sobre cómo lograban usar muy poca RAM para crear los gráficos de los juegos en las pantallas de TV. Pero nuevamente, todo esto se asocia a crear tu propia consola. Creo que deberías definir desde dónde quieres comenzar a aprender realmente y luego ir investigando más y más al respecto.

Comment: Vale, pues igual que le digo a Jose te lo pregunto a ti, renunciando a querer programar la emulación de "hardware", creando la reproducción de música o la captura gráfica, cual de las dos tecnologías expuestas me recomiendas?